# Ruby on Rails I want to output the content of the csv file selected by "file_field_tag" on another tab when "submit_tag" is pressed

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I want to output the content of the csv file selected by

"file_field_tag" on a separate tab when I press "submit_tag".

index.html.erb

```
<%= file_field_tag :file %>
<%= submit_tag "CSV_output" ,class: "btn btn-info", formtarget: "_blank" %>
```

controller

```
def index
    　　　　
end

def import

    @upload_file=params[:file]

end
```

Comment: Sound cool! Go for it!

Answer (score 0):

Hey you'd better have a read on this page first in order to understand how CSV data exporting works for Rails(Ruby)
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Good luck.